# How to get unanswered mails using Java mail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, flags

I have tried

```
ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.ANSWERED), false);
```

to get list of unanswered mails from the inbox but returns all mails from inbox.

```
message.isSet(Flags.Flag.ANSWERED);
```

is also giving same output.

How can I list out read but unanswered mails from the inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IMAP?  If not, this won't work.

It's up to the mail reader to set the ANSWERED flag on a message when you reply to that message.  Some mail readers might not do that.  What mail reader are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using imap.gmail.com

Comment: If you're also using the gmail.com web interface you may need to experiment to see if it sets the ANSWERED flag when you respond to a message.

Answer (score 0):

download the JavaMail API and make sure the relevant jar files are in your classpath.

using the gmail.com web interface you need to change the setting blocked to unblocked to gmail account.
    import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Main {

```
private static String USER_NAME = "*****";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
private static String PASSWORD = "********"; // GMail password
private static String RECIPIENT = "lizard.bill@myschool.edu";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String from = USER_NAME;
    String pass = PASSWORD;
    String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
    String subject = "Java send mail example";
    String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

    sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
}

private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch (AddressException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}